# mysql Select one column twice from the same table with different dates in the where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sql queries which i want to combine in one SQL Query and display on one table:

```
SELECT subname,subscribers as sub1 FROM reports_subreport where  country ='1' and mp='0' and date ='2013-10-15' and NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%')  order by site,subname


SELECT subscribers as sub2 FROM reports_subreport where country ='1' and mp='0' and date ='2013-10-08' and NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%')  order by site,subname
```

Should Display something Like This in a table:

**subname**  **sub1**    **sub2**

ENT            222          202

Could you please help me out here because iam new to mysql and php?

Answer (score 2):

There are some better and professional answers already been given, but this one is best to understand what is going around

```
SELECT subname, 

    (SELECT subscribers 
     FROM reports_subreport 
     WHERE country ='1' AND mp='0' 
     AND date ='2013-10-15' 
     AND NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%') 
     ORDER BY site,subname LIMIT 1) AS sub1,

    (SELECT subscribers 
     FROM reports_subreport 
     WHERE country ='1' AND mp='0' 
     AND date ='2013-10-08' 
     AND NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%') 
     ORDER BY site,subname LIMIT 1) AS sub2,

FROM reports_subreport WHERE country ='1' AND mp='0' 
AND date ='2013-10-15' AND NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%') 
ORDER BY site,subname
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us know if this works.

```
SELECT `subname`, CASE WHEN `date`='2013-10-15' THEN `subscribers` ELSE 'NONE' `s1` , CASE WHEN `date`='2013-10-08' THEN `subscribers` ELSE 'NONE' `s2`
WHERE `country` ='1' AND `mp`='0' AND NOT(`subname` LIKE '%Test%') ORDER BY `site`,`subname`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `IF` in your column selection:

```
SELECT
  subname,
  if(date ='2013-10-15', subscribers) as sub1,
  if(date ='2013-10-08', subscribers) as sub2
FROM reports_subreport
WHERE country ='1' and mp='0' and date IN ('2013-10-15','2013-10-08') and NOT(subname LIKE '%Test%')  order by site,subname
```