# Select one column (with multiple rows) 5 times from the same table with different dates in the where clause

Tags: pivot, mariadb, heidisql

The DB records all user activity daily. I am trying to compile a summary report to display total number of actions per day per user. The problem is I want to stack the results next to each other. I have refered to the following stackoverflow questions.

[mysql Select one column twice from the same table with different dates in the where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374024/mysql-select-one-column-twice-from-the-same-table-with-different-dates-in-the-wh)

[Select two columns from same table with different WHERE conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569227/select-two-columns-from-same-table-with-different-where-conditions)

but I still continue to get the "subquery returns more than one row error #1242". All help is appreciated. Thank you.

This is my query, just for 2 days to start with.

```
  SELECT LOGGEDIN_USER AS EnquiryHero, 

  ( SELECT COUNT(user_id) from applications 
  DATE_TIME like "2016-08-24%" group by user_id ) as Day1, 

  ( SELECT COUNT(user_id)from applications 
  WHERE DATE_TIME like "2016-08-25%" group by user_id ) as Day2, 

  from applications WHERE DATE_TIME like "2016-08-24%" group by user_id;
```

--

```
SELECT user_id, 
( SUM( IF( the_day ='2016-08-24', ct, 0 ))) AS 2016-08-24, 
( SUM( IF( the_day ='2016-08-25', ct, 0 ))) AS 2016-08-25, 
( SUM( IF( the_day ='2016-08-26', ct, 0 ))) AS 2016-08-26, 
( SUM( IF( the_day ='2016-08-27', ct, 0 ))) AS 2016-08-27, 

FROM ( select user_id, DATE(date_time) AS the_day, loggedin_user, COUNT(*) AS ct      
FROM applications GROUP BY 1,2 ) AS x 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: You have at least two syntax errors; please fix them.

Answer (score 0):

First focus on getting the data; then focus on "pivoting" the data.

```
SELECT user_id,
       DATE(`date_time`) AS the_day,
       COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM applications
    GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

See if that gives you the data desired; then look at how to "pivot".  See the extra tag I added.

**Then pivot**

```
SELECT user_id,
       (SUM(IF(the_day = '2016-08-24', ct, 0) AS '2016-08-24',
       (SUM(IF(the_day = '2016-08-25', ct, 0) AS '2016-08-25',
       (SUM(IF(the_day = '2016-08-26', ct, 0) AS '2016-08-26',
       (SUM(IF(the_day = '2016-08-27', ct, 0) AS '2016-08-27',
       ...
    FROM (
             the query above
         ) AS x
    GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Rick James. Yes, it does provide the required data. But it is all displayed as rows...

Comment: Thanks again Rick James. But I have a syntax error #1064. I removed the ... and also included closing brackets for the SUMs and IFs. Added spaces after opening the brackets.. placed the query into the FROM... I'll have to work on the syntax. Added the query to the original question.